# How to validate the answer from database and display the right answer?

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a responsive quiz whereby it allows user to select the difficulty and a set of question will be displayed.(One question per page)

What I want is, whenever the user submits the answer, if the answer is correct,proceeds to next question after and indication like a green tick or something but if the user is wrong, the right answer will be displayed next to the text box where the type their question.

Currently I am able to generate the questions and it is also able to detect if the answer is right or wrong, if it's right there will be marks and if not there will not be.

What my main concern is what is the best way for me to do the validation and display the right answer?
(Sorry I am just a beginner on php and mysql, so if there's any help provided I will be greatly appreciated!)

Comment: Rather than asking such a **broad** question, perhaps give the above an attempt and ask SO about more specific problems, e.g. why am I getting this error?

Have a look at this link to get started:
http://www.smarttutorials.net/responsive-quiz-application-using-php-mysql-jquery-ajax-and-twitter-bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

You need a table of `Questions` and another of `Answers`. When an answer is retrieve from the user, you need to check if correct is `0`(wrong) or `1`(correct)

minimum Tables definition

```
 Question(id int, questionText:tinytext)
 Answers(id int, questionId int, QuestionAnswer tinytext, IsCorrect bit)
```